# Ubuntu - /usr/bin/p4v.bin: not found

Tags: ubuntu, perforce

forgive my ignorance here. I’m trying to install [P4 Visual Client](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-client) on my Ubuntu VM. I’ve done:

```
cp <package>/bin/* /usr/bin
cp <package>/lib/* /usr/lib
chmod +x /usr/bin/p4v
```

When I try to run `./p4v` from the bin directory though, I get:

> /usr/bin/p4v.bin: not found

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are these the installation instructions?  What was in the two directories that you copied?

Comment: Even the dupe instructions are not good.  I wouldn't copy any of that stuff into /usr/bin but instead put it in /usr/local/bin or similar.  Or even /opt.

Comment: @JakeGould, the instructions in your link are not for P4V. They are for the P4 executable, which is a command-line program. P4V is a separate GUI client.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the other binaries in  need are executable as well. The p4v command is just a Bourne shell script that calls p4v.bin, and if that is not executable, it won't be found by the shell.

Key error that gives this away:

> /usr/bin/**p4v.bin**: not found

To solve this problem, use chmod+x on p4v.bin, p4admin, p4admin.bin, p4merge, p4merge.bin, and p4vc.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem on Ubuntu 14.04. 
The solution for this was to download the 64bit P4V from the [perforce site](https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-visual-client-p4v)

I was trying to invoke p4v from a 32bit distribution. I deleted the old files which I copied earlier to /usr/bin/ and copied new files from the 64bit distribution to /usr/bin/ and ran ./p4v

It worked.

You can check the version of the "p4v.bin" file by using the "file" command as shown below.

```
user@myhost:/usr/bin$ file p4v.bin
p4v.bin: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically 
linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, 
BuildID[sha1]=15c91a661725437d080c1a85e830c6683637f40d, stripped
user@myhost:/usr/bin$
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, turned out I was trying to run the 32bit version on a 64bit OS.

Check it with `file p4v.bin`.